# Array index is deleting multiple times from view - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

a bit of background: Building an app that pulls data from two sources (external API and my own database) into one. This entails grabbing data from external source and combining it with what I have internally for each entity.

It is possible to have part of an entities data in one child "div" and a second part in another "div". Only on association (by ID) can they be joined and show only one div. That is my goal anyway...

**Question**

I'm trying to update an index of an array in my child controller. The index of the array is in fact deleted with what I have so far, however it's happening multiple times.

I've created a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NguDwzHEaX4jSS2WzvZH?p=preview) which demonstrates this. If you click on the user one tab and click submit multiple times, it keeps deleting and I can't think of why anymore.

This is the main logic for the action (actions.js), where I am deleting the index and assigning the updated entity to it:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      user_tickets = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.tickets;
      for ( var status in user_tickets ) {
          for ( var i = 0; i < user_tickets[status].length; i++ ) {
              if ( user_tickets[status][i].id === 10 ) {
                  console.log('splicing');
                  console.log(user_tickets[status][i]);
                  user_tickets[status].splice(user_tickets[status].indexOf(i));
                  user_tickets[status][i] = { id: 10, name: 'Latest Issue', notes: "faking an update that adds a 'notes' key" };
              }
          }
      }
      $scope.$parent.tickets = user_tickets;
    });
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code as text in your question.  External links are no substitute for code in the question itself.

Comment: @ryanyuyu done, sorry about that

Comment: `$timeout` - not `setTimeout` with an `$apply()`!!!!!!!!!

Comment: the thing that sticks out to me is the use of `$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent`.  This is a terrible construct.  aside from that, the logic here doesn't really make sense; when you want to update a ticket, you should just be able to update that record; deleting a record and then trying to add another with the same id isn't right.

Comment: @Claies there isn't any deleting going on server-side, i'm just wanting to delete it from the UI. The reason to delete it is because there *can* be two entries for a ticket at a time, and I want to get rid of both of those and display only the latest

Comment: @Claies it is ugly indeed, but it seems that because I have this variable within 2 ng-repeats that's the only way to get to it. I suppose I can always get the root source of the variable from the parent and work off that. But if I do that i might as well reload the entire view to show the correct data i need :P

Comment: This logic still doesn't make sense to me; why would there be two entries for the same item?

Comment: @Claies because the app contains data from two different sources. the idea behind the app is to combine this data and make work less repetitive

Comment: It's not just ugly, it's not maintainable. You can't change the structure of the directive without changing the reference in an otherwise unrelated function logic

Comment: @Claies yeah i can see that, it's not my final "solution", i will work my way up to refactoring once i actually get the dirty solution working as expected

Comment: @Claies my fallback solution is just to reload the view with the new data, but i'd like to leave the user where they were instead of having to make them find the ticket again

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. What is the desired output when you click "submit" ?

Answer (score 2):

Your logic for splicing arrays isn't going to work the way you expect.  since you are removing an object from the array, the array itself is changed, and the next command will not be operating on the same array structure.

For example, If you have an array of 3 objects `[1, 2, 3]`, and want to remove `2` and put a new record in it's place, this is what your current code does:

1. `splice` removes `2` from the array, leaving the array as `[1, 3]`.
2. `array[1]` now points to the object `3`, so using `array[1] = 4` is now going to leave you with an array of `[1, 4]` (not the result you were expecting).

Instead, you should probably loop through the array and remove all the objects, then push a new object to the end of the array with the data you want.

Comment: I will update you once I try this, thanks for pointing this out

Comment: hey Claies, I managed to solve the issue. The UI is now showing the correct arrays within each status, but now I'm just thinking of ways to refactor/test. Thanks for your input, it helped pinpoint where to start looking!

Answer (score 0):

What I did was loop over each array item using [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) where I either add to the arrays object, or remove it based on my own logic.

This seems to work. Now just toying around for side effects!

```
$timeout(function() {
$scope.$apply(function() {
    var new_tickets = {};
    var ticket = resp.data.ticket;
    var user_tickets = $scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.tickets;
    for ( var status in user_tickets ) {
        var regex = new RegExp(status, 'gi');
        var tickets_by_status = user_tickets[status];
        console.log('started with length: ' + tickets_by_status.length);
        tickets_by_status.forEach(function(obj, index, array) {
            if ( ticket.id === obj.id ) {
                console.log('got a match: obj='+obj.id + ' ticket:'+ticket.id);
                console.log(obj.status);
                if ( regex.test(obj.status) ) {
                    console.log('we matched status');
                    array[index] = ticket;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('ticket doesnt belong here anymore, splicing');
                    array.splice(index, 1);
                }
            }
        });
        console.log('ended with length: ' + tickets_by_status.length);
        new_tickets[status] = {};
        new_tickets[status] = tickets_by_status;
    }
    $scope.$parent.tickets = new_tickets;
});
}, 2000);
```